# Is it possible to create an array of unspecified length AND size in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

So  i wanted to create an array that is nXn dimensions. I know it's possible to do it with one dimension but can I do it with two ? Here is my code : the list_length is defined above as an int number and its a sum of rows in a txt file.

```
while (row_size_t==false)
{
    cout << "How many rows?" << endl;
    cin >> rows;
    if (rows<=0)
    {
        cout << "wrong value" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        row_size_t = true;
    }
}
int* joker_array = new int [list_length][rows];
```

Comment: Use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`

Comment: Yes, you can do it with as many dimensions as you need.  However, the setup will become more complex with each dimension added.  [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) does the same thing but will be much easier to use.

Comment: a `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` can contain any number of vectors and those vectors can be of any size, however it isnt the best data-structure, what to use depends on specific needs

Comment: Names that end with `_t` are generally type names. On POSIX systems they are reserved. Don't use names like that for things that aren't types. Change `row_size_t` to something that describes what it actually does. Maybe `row_size_valid`?